# Parse Push Notifications Via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I'm trying to send Push Notifications - using the Parse JS SDK - via angular, and it's only partially working:

The notification is sent, my colleague can catch the notification event in iOS, the notification sound is triggered(cheering.caf), but the **banner never shows**.

Android has no issues - everything works as expected (and the banner does show up).

I'm wrapping all that notification functionality in a service, which I'm injecting into my controller; I copy-pasted that same piece of code into a regular JS script and called it via a button, and the banner did show, so I'm guessing it's something to do with how Angular manages itself?

Every other Parse feature works, so far.

I'm initializing Parse in `run()`, though I also tried initializing it before creating my angular app module.

Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: isnt run() a jasmine function?

Comment: no, the default angularjs `run()` (look under _Module Loading & Dependencies_): https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: tks for clarifying, im reading that link, couldnt be this the reason: You can only inject instances (not Providers)
    // into run blocks